# Why is there no results returned in php, but there are in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM ac_journal WHERE datetime < (SELECT datetime FROM ac_journal WHERE jid = 1089 AND rid IN ('2','3','4')) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

When I execute this query in phpmyadmin, I get a row
[image]

In my code, it is not returning anything.

```
function ac_journal_get_previous_entry($jid)
{
  global $user; //1
  echo $jid; //1089
  echo "<br />'" . implode("','", array_keys($user->roles)) . "'"; //'2','3','4'

  if ($jid > 0)
  {
    $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {ac_journal} WHERE datetime < (SELECT datetime FROM {ac_journal} WHERE jid = ? AND rid IN (?)) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1", array($jid, "'" . implode("','", array_keys($user->roles)) . "'"));
    $obj = $result->fetchAll();
    echo $result->rowCount(); //0

    if (is_array($obj) && count($obj) > 0)
    { 
      echo "HERE"; //never gets here
      return "<a href='https://example.com/journal/" . $obj[0]->jid . "'>Previous</a>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using placeholders `?` but not doing anything with them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it looks like they are in the array, as a second param for `db_query()` -> `array($jid, "'" . implode("','", array_keys($user->roles)) . "'")`

Comment: Why do you have curly brackets around your table name in your php -> `{ac_journal}`?

Comment: @Sean This is the part I'm asking about `WHERE jid = ? AND rid IN (?)` - shouldn't there be some type of binding happening? what am I missing?

Comment: @Sean Because I am using Drupal (7)

Comment: @Fred-ii- it looks like drupal7 [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) does the binding, which is built on PDO

Comment: @Sean *Hm, interesting*. Thanks Sean, I didn't know that *till now*. cheers

Comment: Why don't you try echoing out the query being created and see if it's actually the same as what's working in PHPMyAdmin:


`echo "SELECT * FROM {ac_journal} WHERE datetime < (SELECT datetime FROM {ac_journal} WHERE jid = ? AND rid IN (?)) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1", array($jid, "'" . implode("','", array_keys($user->roles)) . "'")`

Comment: Looking at the comments for [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7), it is suggested to just pass the array when using `IN()` -> `$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {ac_journal} WHERE datetime < (SELECT ...rest of query... LIMIT 1", array($jid, array_keys($user->roles)));`  see  https://api.drupal.org/comment/19019#comment-19019 or https://api.drupal.org/comment/46518#comment-46518

Answer (score 2):

I had to change it to this:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {ac_journal} WHERE datetime < (SELECT datetime FROM {ac_journal} WHERE jid = :jid) AND rid IN (:rid) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1', array(':jid' => $jid, ':rid' => array_keys($user->roles)));
```

Comment: Much cleaner to use named placeholders! +1 for finding your own solution

Answer (score 0):

this line makes no result in echo: `fetchAll();`as in;

```
$obj = $result->fetchAll();
```

try to change it into:

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But, Execute first the array before fetching the object, as in:

```
$obj->execute(array(':jid' => $jid ));
$result = $obj->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (is_array($result) && count($result) > 0){ 
     echo "HERE"
.................
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php